# Basic Tensorflow: Define Tensor variable using existing variables

Tags: tensorflow

I have some very simple tensorflow code to rotate a vector:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 1))
angle = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

s_a = tf.sin(angle)
c_a = tf.cos(angle)
R = tf.Variable([[c_a, s_a], [-s_a, c_a]], tf.float32, expected_shape=(2,2))
#R = tf.Variable([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]], tf.float32)
rotated_v = tf.matmul(R,x)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    res =  sess.run([init,rotated_v], feed_dict={x:np.array([[1.0],[1.0]]), angle:1.0})
    print(res)
```

The code works fine when I hand-code the identity matrix. However, in its current form I get this error:

```
ValueError: initial_value must have a shape specified: Tensor("Variable/initial_value:0", dtype=float32)
```

I've tried specifying the shape in multiple ways, but I can't make this work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to achieve this (might not be the best way, but it works).

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(2, 1))
angle = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

s_a = tf.sin(angle)
c_a = tf.cos(angle)
R = tf.Variable([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]], tf.float32)
assignR = tf.assign(R, [[c_a, s_a], [-s_a, c_a]])

rotated_v = tf.matmul(R,x)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    newR = sess.run(assignR, feed_dict={angle:1.0})
    print(newR)
    print()

    res =  sess.run([rotated_v], feed_dict={x:np.array([[1.0],[1.0]])})
    print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work, because `s_a` and `c_a` are the *ops outputs*, which values are uniquely determined by `angle`. You can't assign or update these nodes, so training them doesn't make any sense.

This line, on the other hand...

```
R = tf.Variable([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]], tf.float32)
```

... is a definition of an independent variable with *initial value* equal to identity matrix. This is perfectly valid. Since this variable is independent, you can assign a new value to it, which consists of `s_a` and `c_a`. Note that you can't initialize it with `s_a` and `c_a`, because the initializer is run before the values are fed into a session (so `angle` is unknown).